# Why mysqld set user/group of /var/log/mysql with ‘s’ rights?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, administrator

In Ubuntu, `sudo apt-get install mysql-server`, the package will:

- create an account `mysql`
- create storage directory `/var/lib/mysql` with permission `drwx------  4 mysql mysql`
- create log directory `/var/log/mysql` with permission `drwxr-s---  2 mysql adm`

Why? In my mind, the permission of `/var/log/mysql` should be `drwxr-x---  4 mysql mysql`.
Could you give me some insight/convention about the `s` bit and 'adm' group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### g+rx

Since mysqld runs under the `mysql` account, which is already the *owner* of `/var/lib/mysql`, only the "user" permission bits apply; there is no need at all to grant any access to the group. (It might even risk creating security problems, if a clueless admin adds regular users to the `mysql` group; if the directory was g+rx, that would allow such users to bypass MySQL privilege checks.)

#### g+s

On directories, the ["setgid" g+s bit](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/permissions/) means new items created inside will inherit their group from the directory, not from the process. This means that all log files will be owned by :adm, regardless of what groups mysqld itself is in.

#### adm

Granting read access to system log files is practically the only purpose of "adm". (In the past, those used to be kept in `/usr/adm`, which of course was the home directory of the `adm` user account.)

I'm not entirely sure about the origins of its name, though my guess is that the distinction was between 'operators' who did system management stuff, and 'administrators' who took care of accounting & payments based on the system usage logs.

Comment: Very clear explanation.